# Application icon badge is not displayed

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I set app icon badge using

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = ...;
```

I change its value on multiples classes. In one of the classes I ma having  issue that

```
NSLog(@"App icon badge : %d", [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber);
```

prints some value.e.g. `4`. But if I put app in background then there is no badge on icon. It should display badge `4`.

I also change badge value in another class. In that it sets correct value and putting app in background shows correct value.

What happens is I am in controller, in which setting of badge value works, and log current badge value then it gives the correct value and putting app in background also shows correct value. But then if go to another controller, in which settings of badge is not working, and log badge value then it always prints 0.

Comment: I would say: change it on the main thread only... but I dont know. the docs dont say that but from my experience with apple OSs Id do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It was due to below code of parse.

```
PFInstallation * currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
currentInstallation.badge = 0;
[currentInstallation saveEventually:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
        ALog(@"Parse error in setting badge on installation object. Error : %@", error);
    }
}];
```

After below line it was setting app icon badge to 0.

```
currentInstallation.badge = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

set your Badge value in this method :-

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application 

                       **OR** 

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: I also change badge value in another class. In that it sets correct value and putting app in background shows correct value.

Comment: @chewy why only there?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set badge value in  appdelegate's different method like below:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: I also change badge value in another class. In that it sets correct value and putting app in background shows correct value.

Comment: @Stranger why only there?

Comment: It's Because i Know as a programamer you are handling to set Badge Value on all Class. But the while app is in going to backgroung or come from background. No one set badge value. according to apple docs. We can use the above methods to perform certain operation on application.